# How can I check Apache is not allowing outgoing requests?

Tags: apache, authorize.net

We have an online form program that allows users to submit payment to Authorize.net (or PayPal, Stripe, etc).

On our internally hosted environment, all the forms without payment requirements work perfectly - we receive the form data, notifications go out to users, etc. However, when we add a payment option to a form, we still get the form data but the submission of the payment fails.

It doesn't go anywhere- Authorize.net is never pinged. As a test, I set up an instance of the form program on a Dreamhost space I have and the payment processing works perfectly. That's why I narrowed the issue to our server.

Any tips on how I might be able to tweak our Apache server to allow the submissions? Or even where I should look?